# How to run a script on startup for Old Linux kernel (3.0.0)

Tags: linux, boot, script, upstart

I need to run a script on system startup, but the Linux version is very old, so:

1. There is no `rc.local`. Even when I created it and gave it a command, it was never run.
2. There is no `crontab` at all.
3. Adding the script to `init.d` also didn't produce any result.
4. Obviously there is no Upstart app, and it's not possible to install as I can only access the device through ssh.

I'm sure the script itself works, as it works when I manually run it of course. The device is an embedded Linux device (Ettus E100, [link](http://www.ettus.com/product/details/UE100-KIT)). My Linux version is 3.0.0, and here is the exact version:

1. `$ cat /proc/version` returns:
   `Linux version 3.0.0 (oe-classic@oebuild) (gcc version 4.5.3 20110311 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 Thu Mar 28 18:15:38 PDT 2013`.
2. `$ dmesg | head -1` returns: 
   `[    0.000000] Linux version 3.0.0 (oe-classic@oebuild) (gcc version 4.5.3 20110311 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 Thu Mar 28 18:15:38 PDT 2013`.
3. `$ runlevel` returns: `N 5`.
4. `$ cat /etc/issue` returns nothing.
5. `$ cat /etc/*-release` returns error 'No such file or directory'.
6. `$ lsb_release -a` returns error 'command not found'.
7. `$ uname -a` returns: `Linux ettus-e1xx 3.0.0 #1 Thu Mar 28 18:15:38 PDT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux`.

Not sure how else to check my distribution.

Are there any alternative means to get the script to run at startup?

Comment: 1) The 3.0.0 kernel is not very old. 2) The init mechanism has nothing to do with the kernel. 3) => Tell us which Linux distro you use and which version of it.

Comment: @ClassStacker Hello, I edited the question with more details.

Comment: So is this a commercial specialised appliance, maybe from Ettus as `uname -a` suggests? According to their website, the latest version would be based on Ubuntu 12, but hey, we can't know which version of this stick you have. But _you_ should know because you bought it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The command: `ln -s /etc/rc.local /etc/rc5.d/S99rclocal` gets the script to run on startup for this embedded Linux version.